# How to do Icon Prefixes on Select or Multi select Form elements using Material Design CSS?

Tags: html, css, select, material-design

How do you use 'icon prefixes' for select form elements in [Material Design CSS](http://materializecss.com)? According the documentation,

> You can add an icon prefix to make the form input label even more clear. Just add an icon with the class `prefix` before the input and label.

This method worked for regular input boxes, but not on `<select>` elements see below:

[image]

How do I get this to work in the `<select>` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After banging my head on the wall for a while, I looked at the core css files and found this:

```css
.input-field .prefix ~ input, .input-field .prefix ~ textarea {
    margin-left: 3rem;
    width: 92%;
    width: calc(100% - 3rem);
}
```

You can see from the source code that, there was no provision made for `<select>` form elements. To fix the issue, just add this css script to your source, and that solves the case:

```css
.input-field .prefix ~ .select-wrapper {
  margin-left:3rem; 
  width:92%; 
  width:calc(100% - 3rem);
}
```

The results were as expected - 
[image]